# Drupal 7 custom module menu hook is not working

Tags: 7, routes

I have created D7 module called 'mymodule' and enabled it from module list page.
But the menu created inside the mymodule_menu() is not being called, instead redirects to 404 page.

Below is the mymodule.info file

```
name = my custom module
description = My module testing
version = 7.x
package = Custom Modules
core=7.x
```

Below is the mymodule.module file

```
<?php
echo 'Module is called';

function mymodule_menu() {

    $items['mydesk'] =  array(
      'title' => 'My Desk' ,
      'page callback' => 'show_mydesk',
      'access arguments' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
}

function show_mydesk() {
    echo 'show_mydesk';
}
```

Note: the echo 'Module is called' text is printing after enabled the module.
Any help to find out where I have missed something.

Thanks
Govind

Comment: Don't use echo, just return the text you want. Are you accessing yoursite.com/mydesk, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `access arguments` with `access callback`.

Replace following code:

```
$items['mydesk'] =  array(
  'title' => 'My Desk' ,
  'page callback' => 'show_mydesk',
  'access arguments' => TRUE,
);
```

With:

```
$items['mydesk'] =  array(
  'title' => 'My Desk' ,
  'page callback' => 'show_mydesk',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
);
```

Comment: Yes, It woks when only 'access callback' is present. Thanks dude